# How to model charcoal grate's rods?

Tags: 3ds-max, modeling

What modifier to use for transform horizontal rods by arc like at this photo? I try to transform manually, but it is very slow.
[image]

Comment: Are you trying to create the circular ring along the outside (it's called a Torus) or are you trying to clip the horizontal cylinders to the shape of that torus?

Comment: Also, 3D questions are a bit of an odd fit for this site, because not many of us are 3D animators/modelers.  There is a [proposed 3DSE here](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/86368/3d-graphics) that you should go and commit to.

Comment: Manly, I'm trying to to clip the horizontal cylinders to the shape of that torus. Also I'm trying to use the "Taper" modifier, but the result does not satisfy me, form gets enough round.

Answer (score 2):

I use Cinema 4D, so the options might be slightly different, but the process should be the same.  As I mentioned, 3D questions are a bit tricky on this site and usually wind up closed. I'm only answering this, because I'm on lunch break and haven't used C4D in ages, so I wanted to make sure I still had the skills.

Start with a cylinder

[image]

I then placed the cylinder into a cloner object, using the following settings

[image]

[image]

Now that you have your grate, it's time to cut the bars to a circular path.  I did this by using a Boolean object, with the following settings

[image]

The hierarchy within the boole object is important, notice how mine is stacked

[image]

The cylinder on the bottom is the one that will "cut" the grate, so set its diameter to whatever you'd like

Add a Torus (use the same pipe diameter as your initial cylinder and ring radius as the cylinder you used for the boolean cutout) and voila!

[image]

Comment: I haven't tried to make this in Cinema 4D, but answer is useful. Thank you.